# Css Best Practice Dilemma - specific case

Tags: css

A client asks for an admin table and one column will have different cell colors based on some rules.

My problem is : what is the best css practice for this.

- we know inline is bad from the start
- we could do some css classes for each color and give them a good name but this will just clutter then main css file with classes that will probably never be used again.

So what would be a good approach for this simple problem ?

Comment: How many colors and what do the colors represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what would be a good approach for this simple problem ?

You have essentially already outlined your two options. It's your choice.

I would always go with classes, and never with inline CSS. If you're worried about cluttering, you could add some order using comments:

```
/** Table highlight styles **/

table.data td.highlight { background-color: #CCCCCC }
table.data td.total     { background-color: #ABCDEF }
```

You could theoretically put these into a separate CSS file, but the number of style sheets should be kept as low as possible. To do this right, you could use a CSS preprocessor as suggested by @Ian.... but that is an entirely different and new can of worms.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would recommend using something like [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/)(DotNet) or [less](http://lesscss.org/) (Ruby).

Here you can define a colour like `@MyMainColour` and then have `div.SomeBackground { background: @MyMainColour; }`

These tools will allow you to "compile" your CSS compress and turn out customer specific themes.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider:

Keep a separate css file for specific adjustments. This might be a good compromise between keeping a main style file uncluttered, but still be able to target specific GUIs with adjustments.

Let a GUI have an id. This way you can let GUI specific adjustments only affect that GUI with styles given in context.

Comment: While there's nothing technically wrong about this suggestion, unless there's A LOT of extra stuff, this is actually more work than just adding to the main sheet, marked off with a comment, and adds an extra HTTP request to your pages, for very little benefit.

Comment: It depends on the amount of GUIs and adjustments - it's a cost-benefit consideration.  Improved readability of main stylesheet and ease of looking up custom adjustments are big benefits, though.